# html (javascript?) всегда открывать новую вкладку при нажатии кнопки формы

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть html форма с полем select, в котором пользователь выбирает таблицу из базы mySql, которую ему покажут.

```html
<form action = "tableOutput.php" method="post" name="frmTableSelect" target="_blank"> 
    <p>Выберите таблицу из списка</p>
    <select name="tableName" autofocus>
<!-- здесь загрузка списка таблиц из mySql. для упрощения, пусть так: -->
        <option>table 1</option>
    <option>table 2</option>
     <p><br><input name="submit" type="submit" value="показать таблицу"></p>
 </form>
```

Когда нажимаешь кнопку, открывается новая вкладка с таблицей (обрабатываю в файле "tableOutput.php").

Но если вернуться обратно к форме и выбрать в select другую (или ту же таблицу), то новый результат открывается *в той же вкладке*, что предыдущий, т.е. *заменяет* его собой.

Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы каждое нажатие кнопки *всегда* открывало новую вкладку.

Я вставила javascript:

```html
<script>
  knopka.submit = function() {   
    window.open("tableOutput.php")
  };
</script>
```

Так ничего не изменилось.

Если сделать:

```html
<script>
      knopka.onclick = function() { 
        window.open("tableOutput.php")
      };
 </script>
```

новая вкладка открывается при каждом нажатии, но так не работает Post метод и код в "tableOutput.php" даёт ошибки.

Comment: А вывод информации осуществляется в  tableOutput.php или потом перекидывает на другую страницу?

Comment: в tableOutput.php у меня код, который обращается в базу, вынимает содержимое выбранной таблицы и выкладывает его в табличку на экране (её строю, используя html).

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, вы получаете данный таким способом

```
$label = $_POST["tableName"];
```

По идее у вас в форме есть `target="_blank"`, поэтому при клике на кнопку должно открываться каждый раз в новом окне.

Можно отменить браузерное событие при клике на кнопку отправку формы, и сделать это на javascript

Для этого добавить id

```
<form id="form" action = "test.php" method="post" name="frmTableSelect" target="_blank">
```

И сам код обработки

```
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault()
console.log(1)
    })
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136733/discussion-on-answer-by--html-javascript----).

Answer (score 0):

Мне ответили на англоязычном форуме.
Вот этот код делает то, что мне нужно:

```html
let cnt = 0;
document.querySelector("[name=frmTableSelect]").addEventListener("submit", function() {
  this.target=`win${cnt++}`;
})
```

Я не вполне его понимаю, честно говоря, пойду читать документацию. Ура.

Comment: Отлично, рад за вас. 
Добавил на хостинг ваш пример, при клике открывается в новой вкладке, или я что-то не правильно понимаю? Посмотрите пожалуйста
http://calc.helpsycheva.ru

Comment: да, всё правильно.
спасибо вам за уделённое время.

Comment: Если все правильно работает, можете тогда не использовать javascript. Если не сложно тогда кликните по стрелочке вверх, рядом с моим ответом. Ответ я свой поправил